# Would this question about Aramaic be on topic?

Tags: discussion

> Which modern day dialect of Aramaic is the closest one to the dialect that Jesus of Nazareth spoke in Palestine some 2000 years ago?

Would this question be on topic on the main site?

If not, where can I post it?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Which-forms-of-modern-Aramaic-are-closest-to-Biblical-Aramaic

Comment: Cross post on BH.SE meta: [Would this question about Aramaic be on topic?](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/3326)

Comment: Follow up: This question was [asked on linguistics.se](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/19293/201).

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't close it, but you'll get better answers on https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is the honest type of answer that I am looking for. Thank you for being frank about it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with question standards for meta but the best answer seems to be http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/ mentioned in Caleb's cross post, seems to be the best answer.       For cross posted questions, is it best to duplicate the answer, then accept the duplicated answer?

Comment: @nick Sites are separate entities entirely. Caleb provided good information that would do well here too. There's no reason not to duplicate it here. I'll edit it into my answer tomorrow morning.

Comment: P.S.  Especially considering @Caleb asked his question on linguistics.SE and is getting answers there.